# Failed to upgrade or update package in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

everyone here
I tried to upgrade package with software update

And I get error message

The upgrade needs a total of 64.9 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 64.9 M of disk space on '/boot'. You can remove old kernels using 'sudo apt autoremove', and you could also set COMPRESS=xz in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to reduce the size of your initramfs.

Here is a list of files that are on my `/boot` partition

```
ls /boot
config-4.15.0-50-generic  config-4.4.0-159-generic      lost+found                    System.map-4.15.0-55-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-54-generic
config-4.15.0-51-generic  grub                          memtest86+.bin                System.map-4.15.0-58-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic
config-4.15.0-52-generic  initrd.img-4.15.0-50-generic  memtest86+.elf                System.map-4.4.0-150-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-151-generic
config-4.15.0-54-generic  initrd.img-4.15.0-51-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin      System.map-4.4.0-151-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-159-generic
config-4.15.0-55-generic  initrd.img-4.15.0-52-generic  System.map-4.15.0-50-generic  System.map-4.4.0-159-generic
config-4.15.0-58-generic  initrd.img-4.15.0-54-generic  System.map-4.15.0-51-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-50-generic
config-4.4.0-150-generic  initrd.img-4.15.0-55-generic  System.map-4.15.0-52-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-51-generic
config-4.4.0-151-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-151-generic  System.map-4.15.0-54-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-52-generic
```

How can I clean the folder in `/boot`?

---updated main body as followed----

If I follow the instructions `sudo apt autoremove`, I will get the message below.

```
sudo apt autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up uuid-runtime (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.8) ...
insserv: warning: script 'upsMonitor' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service torque-scheduler and upsMonitor if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service upsMonitor at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service torque-scheduler at depth 1
insserv: Stopping upsMonitor depends on torque-scheduler and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package uuid-runtime (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-159-generic (4.4.0-159.187) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-159-generic (4.4.0-159.187) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 4.4.0-159-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' -j16 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=4.4.0-159-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/4.4.0-159-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd modules.......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for nvidia-396: 396.37 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-159-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-396/396.37/build/make.log for more information.
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-159-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-159-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-159-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 uuid-runtime
 linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-159-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I can not remove older kernel whth `sudo apt autoremove`.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions right there in the message you received?

Comment: I tried to followed the instruction `sudo apt autoremove`, and I got more error message as main body what I updated.

Comment: Please provide a `df -sh`. Currently it looks like your /boot partition is simply filled up.

Comment: `df -h
udev             63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G  326M   13G   3% /run
/dev/sda3       1.1T  754G  280G  73% /
tmpfs            63G  140M   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7396
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7713
/dev/sdb1       1.9T  1.4T  463G  76% /data
/dev/sda1       464M  442M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs            13G  124K   13G   1% /run/user/1001
`
Yes, `/boot` partition is filled up.

Comment: And I want to know which file in `/boot` can be removed.